# How to make a process wait

Tags: java, runtime, external

I have a code that execute an external program. And now I need that my application wait the end of the execution of that external program.

But I'm not shure how I supposed to do that. I tried some things but don't work.

```java
public Image acquireImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+ApplicationProperties.getPath()
                + "\\.wimdesktop\\Release\\Static_GenerateGain.exe");

        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("EXIT: " + process.exitValue());
        
        return copyImage();
}
```

The problem is that the `System.out.println("EXIT: " + process.exitValue());` print 0 but the external program still running.

Answer (score 1):

You are running cmd.exe and asking it to start a process in the background. So all you are seeing is cmd.exe exit status 0 after it launches your app - and that app may still be running.

If you want waitFor to apply to the sub-process just run the exe directly without the launch wrapper:

```
 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ApplicationProperties.getPath()
            + "\\.wimdesktop\\Release\\Static_GenerateGain.exe");
```

Note that if your EXE depends on environment variables set by CMD.EXE then you may need to try your original command without "start" for background process:

```
 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c "+ApplicationProperties.getPath()
            + "\\.wimdesktop\\Release\\Static_GenerateGain.exe");
```

In both cases above you may run into second issue that the command freezes, this is because you are not reading the Stdout and error streams. There are many SO posts on how to do this.

Comment: Ah good point. Yes, the OP is querying `cmd` which returns right away.